# Retornar o período em que apresenta a maior quantidade de registros em uma tabela

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados

Estou montando uma query a partir de uma mesma tabela do meu banco que precise retornar (como dito no título) o período (mensal, por exemplo) em que apresenta a maior quantidade de cadastros.

Acontece que eu já tenho um SQL montado para contar a quantidade de registros existentes a partir do período informado pelo usuário. Vejam abaixo:

```
Select
    Sel.Mes,
    MAX(Sel.Total_Cadastrados)
from (
       Select
            Count(*) as Total_cadastrados,
            extract(month from p.dt_cadastro) as Mes
        from Pessoa p
        where cast(p.dt_cadastro as Date) between :ini and :fin
        order by p.dt_cadastro) Sel
group by Mes;
```

Porém eu também teria que retornar neste mesmo SQL qual foi o período (mês no caso) que teve maior nº de cadastros. Então se eu selecionar do dia 01/01/2021 - 31/03/2021 o SQL acima vai trazer a soma de todos os cadastros, e isso não é o que eu quero. Vejam abaixo como fica:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de uma dica de como posso fazer isso,

Agradeço antecipadamente!

Comment: Qual o banco de dados utilizado?

Comment: DbForgeStudio, mas também uso o MYSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voẽ pode fazer o que quer da seguinte maneira:

1. Agrupa os meses e conta a quantidade de registros;
2. Ordena a quantidade total por ordem decrescente (maior para o menor);
3. Limita o resultado;

```
 
    select DATE_FORMAT(p.dt_cadastro,'%m/%Y') as mes,
               count(*) as total_cadastrados
        from pessoa p
         where cast(p.dt_cadastro as Date) between '2020-01-01'
                                               and '2020-03-31'
         group by DATE_FORMAT(p.dt_cadastro,'%m/%Y')
        order by count(*) desc
    limit 1;
```

Dessa forma você poderia inclusive, deixar sua query mais flexivél... dando resultados do tipo o top 5 meses com maior número de pessoas cadastradas, apenas manipulando o limit

Espero ter ajudado :)

Comment: Perfeito, muito obrigado!

Comment: Muito feliz em poder ajudar :)